# Storybook V9 useTransition reverse order

Tags: react-spring

Spring V8 I use to do:

```
bottomTransition.reverse()
```

To get the animations to play in the reverse order do cards [1 ~ 5] would come out in the order 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.
Under react-spring V9 I can no longer just .reverse() the reply because it's now a function call.
So [1 ~ 5] becomes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I tried the `sort` method found: https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-transition#sort

However this just reverses the order of the cards in the deck not the order they come out. So [1 ~ 5] becomes [5 ~ 1] but now they come out 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I just want the animation order to be reversed.

```
  const bottomTransition = useTransition(
    bottomTeamState,
    {
      from: { transform: "translate3d(-700%, 0, 0)" },
      enter: { transform: "translate3d(0%, 0, 0)" },
      leave: { transform: "translate3d(700%, 0, 0)" },
      trail: 175,
      config: {clamp:   true, mass: 3, tension: 150, friction: 38 },
  });

bottomTransition(( style, item, transition, index )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const bottomArray = [
    useTransition(
      bottomTeamState[0],
      {
        from: { transform: "translate3d(-700%, 0, 0)" },
        enter: { transform: "translate3d(0%, 0, 0)" },
        leave: { transform: "translate3d(700%, 0, 0)" },
        trail: 175,
        delay: 175+175+175+175+175,
        // sort: (a, b) => { return -1 },
        // config: config.slow,
        config: { clamp: true, mass: 3, tension: 150, friction: 38 }, // https://react-spring.io/common/configs
      }),
    useTransition(
      bottomTeamState[1],
      {
        from: { transform: "translate3d(-700%, 0, 0)" },
        enter: { transform: "translate3d(0%, 0, 0)" },
        leave: { transform: "translate3d(700%, 0, 0)" },
        trail: 175,
        delay: 175+175+175+175,
        // sort: (a, b) => { return -1 },
        // config: config.slow,
        config: { clamp: true, mass: 3, tension: 150, friction: 38 }, // https://react-spring.io/common/configs
      }),
    useTransition(
      bottomTeamState[2],
      {
        from: { transform: "translate3d(-700%, 0, 0)" },
        enter: { transform: "translate3d(0%, 0, 0)" },
        leave: { transform: "translate3d(700%, 0, 0)" },
        trail: 175,
        delay: 175+175+175,
        // sort: (a, b) => { return -1 },
        // config: config.slow,
        config: { clamp: true, mass: 3, tension: 150, friction: 38 }, // https://react-spring.io/common/configs
      }),
    useTransition(
      bottomTeamState[3],
      {
        from: { transform: "translate3d(-700%, 0, 0)" },
        enter: { transform: "translate3d(0%, 0, 0)" },
        leave: { transform: "translate3d(700%, 0, 0)" },
        trail: 175,
        delay: 175+175,
        // sort: (a, b) => { return -1 },
        // config: config.slow,
        config: { clamp: true, mass: 3, tension: 150, friction: 38 }, // https://react-spring.io/common/configs
      }),
    useTransition(
      bottomTeamState[4],
      {
        from: { transform: "translate3d(-700%, 0, 0)" },
        enter: { transform: "translate3d(0%, 0, 0)" },
        leave: { transform: "translate3d(700%, 0, 0)" },
        trail: 175,
        // sort: (a, b) => { return -1 },
        // config: config.slow,
        config: { clamp: true, mass: 3, tension: 150, friction: 38 }, // https://react-spring.io/common/configs
      }),
  ]
```